# Am I using the wrong validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my DDL and RequiredFieldValidator:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrentlyActive" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Select Option" Selected="True" disabled="diaabled" />
     <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="True" />
     <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="False" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select if the job is active or no active." ControlToValidate="ddlCurrentlyActive" ForeColor="red" />
```

I figured if I disabled the 'Select Option' and added a RequiredFieldValidator it would prevent them from being able to select the 'Select Option'.  But it seems when the page loads this option is selected and if they don't change it it tries to pass that as the value for the database leading to a truncated error.

Can this work with a RequiredFieldValidator?  Or do I need a RegularExpressionValidator and if so how would I set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to assign some value to the default option:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Option" Selected="True" Value="0" />
```

And then tell validator that this value is initial and should be treated as invalid. You can do this with `InitialValue` attribute:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7"
                            runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Please select if the job is active or no active."
                            ControlToValidate="ddlCurrentlyActive"
                            InitialValue="0"
                            ForeColor="red" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the InitialValue property of RequiredValidator.
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What Andrei said should work, but there is another way to do it.  You can simply provide a blank value for your default option and that will kick off the validator without having to provide the InitialValue parameter on the validator

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrentlyActive" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Select Option" Selected="True" Value="" />
     <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="True" />
     <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="False" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select if the job is active or no active." ControlToValidate="ddlCurrentlyActive" ForeColor="red" />
```